# react cannot update state with easy peasy

Tags: reactjs, easy-peasy

**model.js**

```
import axios from "axios"
import { action } from "easy-peasy"

export default {
    video: [],

    // Actions
    getVideo: action((state, id) => {
            axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/videos/${id}`)
            .then(res => {
                state.video = res.data[0]
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
    })
}
```

**Main.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useStore, useStoreActions } from 'easy-peasy'

const Watch = () => {
    const video = useStore(state => state.video)
    const getVideo = useStoreActions(actions => actions.getVideo)

    useEffect(() => {
        getVideo(1)
        console.log(video)
    })

    return (
        <></>
    )
```

I just started using easy-peasy so bear with me... I have no idea why the state is not being updated, I saw some sample code and it was updating the state the same way I was, the getVideo action gets called so thats not the problem, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect(() => {
        getVideo(1)
        console.log(video)
    })
```

Here `console.log(video)` is not called after `getVideo(1)` executed completely. It is natural that `console.log` shows the same data.

You can see that it actually changed as follow.

```
 useEffect(() => {
            getVideo(1)
        })
    console.log(video)
```